# Standard control transparency. Possible?

Tags: winapi, controls

I have a button (`WC_BUTTON`) and I want it to be semitransparent and blend with background. My naive approach was to use `WS_EX_LAYERED` style. Unfortunately `CreateWindowEx()` returns me `ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS` in that case. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Layered child windows are supported in Windows 8.1, but not earlier. I'm not sure what that error message would signify though.

Comment: That's sad (. Thank you.

Comment: Prior to Win8.1, you will have to owner-draw the button manually (see the `BS_OWNERDRAW` button style and `WM_DRAWITEM` message).  When you draw the button, grab an image of the current background, draw a semi-transparent image of a button on top of it as needed, and then draw your completed image to the provided `HDC`.